# ERROR: 'Premature end of file.'

Tags: java, grails, pdf-generation, itext

```
import java.io.*;
import com.lowagie.text.DocumentException;
import org.xhtmlrenderer.pdf.ITextRenderer;

public class FirstDoc {

    public static void main(String[] args) 
        throws IOException, DocumentException {

        String url= "http://www.facebook.com";

        String outputFile = "firstdoc.pdf";
        OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);

        ITextRenderer renderer = new ITextRenderer();
        renderer.setDocument(url);
        renderer.layout();
        renderer.createPDF(os);

        os.close();
    }
}
```

But i am getting this error

```
> ERROR:  'Premature end of file.'
Exception in thread "main" org.xhtmlrenderer.util.XRRuntimeException: Can't load the XML resource (using TRaX transformer). org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Premature end of file.
at org.xhtmlrenderer.resource.XMLResource$XMLResourceBuilder.createXMLResource(XMLResource.java:191)
at org.xhtmlrenderer.resource.XMLResource.load(XMLResource.java:71)
at org.xhtmlrenderer.swing.NaiveUserAgent.getXMLResource(NaiveUserAgent.java:205)
at org.xhtmlrenderer.pdf.ITextRenderer.loadDocument(ITextRenderer.java:102)
at org.xhtmlrenderer.pdf.ITextRenderer.setDocument(ITextRenderer.java:106)
at com.test.java.FirstDoc.main(FirstDoc.java:17)

Caused by: javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Premature end of file.
at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerImpl.transform(TransformerImpl.java:720)
at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerImpl.transform(TransformerImpl.java:313)
at org.xhtmlrenderer.resource.XMLResource$XMLResourceBuilder.createXMLResource(XMLResource.java:189)
... 5 more
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Premature end of file.
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1231)
at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerImpl.transformIdentity(TransformerImpl.java:637)
at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerImpl.transform(TransformerImpl.java:708)
... 7 more
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most likely `http://www.facebook.com` does not return a HTML document, but a HTTP redirect or something, and `ITextRenderer` probably does not support that.

You should verify this by testing with some URL, which does not do a redirect.

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting a premature end of file error when Adding the second Signature to a  pdf file using IText, please make sure you are doing following things right.

- The second  Signature should have a different name than the first one
- Signatures should be added in append mode. eg: (PdfStamper.createSignature(reader, os, '\0', null, append);
- Make sure pdf Certification level should be such that to support adding a second signature field. eg:(appearance.setCertificationLevel(PdfSignatureAppearance.NOT_CERTIFIED);)
- If it's a visible signature make sure the second signature is in a different location visually.